# powershell multiline regex capture and replace

Tags: regex, powershell

I looked around, not finding this specific format, reaching out here.

I have a file that is formatted funny. I'm trying to formulate a regex expression to replace text.

So I have a file that is formatted like below.

The only part I'm interested in are the blocks of [ash01], [ask02], etc..

I would like to grab that whole block, change the FTP server name only, then write the file back.
Before:

```
[ash01]
FTP Server Name     = ftp-server-01
ftp parameter1      = C:\scripts
ftp parameter2      = -t
```

After:

```
[ash01]
FTP Server Name     = ftp-server-05
ftp parameter1      = C:\scripts
ftp parameter2      = -t
```

The file itself has some unformatted data above and below the block in question, then it starts to get into groups like below

```
Unformatted data......
[blah]

[ash01]
FTP Server Name     = ftp-server-01
ftp parameter1      = C:\scripts
ftp parameter2      = -t

[ash02]
FTP Server Name     = ftp-server-02
ftp parameter1      = C:\scripts
ftp parameter2      = -t

[ash03]
FTP Server Name     = ftp-server-03
ftp parameter1      = C:\scripts
ftp parameter2      = -t

[blah]
unformatted data.....
```

Comment: why regex? perhaps read the entire file, find the line with `[ash01]` and then the next line is the line you want to replace. loop again for next entry, etc.  may not be the most efficient, but my guess is it would suit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just a one liner in PowerShell using a [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(Get-Content .\yourfile.txt -raw) -replace "(?SMI)(?<=^\[ash01\]`r?`nFTP Server Name *= *).*?$","ftp-server-05"| Set-Content .\newfile.txt
```

The `[]` have to be escaped with a backslash to not being interpreted as a range.
`(?SMI)` instruct the RegEx to match `^*` line begin/end and multiline and ignore case.

In summary all text to line end is replaced **IF**
the text is preceeded by `[ash01]`, cr/lf, `FTP Server Name` any number of spaces, equal sign any number of spaces.